# Entire div is clickable. The div has an icon in the corner, and I want the div to not be clicked when clicking this icon

Tags: html, css, react-router

[image]

Everything in the image above is inside of a React-Router **Link** tag. Clicking any of the gray area takes the user to a page with more info about 'onion'. The heart is a font-awesome **i** tag, and it has an onClick handler that adds the clicked-on recipe to the user's favorites. Clicking it does successfully favorite the post, but it also triggers the underlying Link, taking the user to the more details page.

How can I click the heart without clicking the Link attached to the underlying div?

Note: The gray box is the element with className="recipecard-content-FEED". Other notes are commented in the code below.

JSX code for this div:

```
<Link to={{pathname: `/recipe/${recipe.id}`, component: 'Feed'}}>
    <div className="recipecard-content-FEED" }> // This is the gray box

        <div className="recipe-title-FEED-container">
            <h1 className="recipe-title-FEED">{recipe.title}</h1> // This is 'onion'
            {this.renderAddOrRemoveFavorite(recipe)} // This renders the heart
        </div>

        <p className="recipe-author-FEED"></p> // This is 'bammbi'

        <h2 className="recipe-cooktime-FEED">{recipe.cooktime}</h2> // This is '20'

    </div>
</Link>
```

The heart:

```
<div className="favorite_btn" onClick={() => this.addFavorite(this.props.auth.user.id, recipe.id)}>
    <i className="far fa-heart"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two options to solve this.

1. adding Click event on heart, and prevent default after it gets added to favorites.
2. Remove link router and route using click event . and tract target with ID.

   If 'id; of target element is heart then ignore routing else route it to details page.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `onClick` function to the icon to prevent the link from going through, and then specify what you want to happen after clicking the icon.

```
const handleClick = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  // handle click behavior here
}

<i className="far fa-heart" onClick={handleClick} />
```

Comment: I added an onClick. Updated my original post to show the new code. I added it to an outer div as font-awesome recommends keeping their icons as is and adding additional functionality to a parent container. It still triggers the underlying link unfortuantely.

Comment: Your function needs to take in the event object and call `preventDefault` before `this.addFavorite` to stop triggering the link.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a messy solution that works:

Instead of making the entire gray container a Link, I can make each individual item within it a Link. This way, the heart works as intended, and clicking anywhere on the box beside other links still takes the you to the more details page.

```
        <div className="recipecard-content-FEED" style={ this.getRecipePicture(recipe) }>

            <div className="recipe-title-FEED-container">
              <Link to={{pathname: `/recipe/${recipe.id}`, component: 'Feed'}}>
                <div className="recipe-title-FEED">
                  <h1>{recipe.title}</h1>
                </div>
              </Link>
              {this.renderAddOrRemoveFavorite(recipe)}
            </div>

            <Link to={{pathname: `/recipe/${recipe.id}`, component: 'Feed'}}>
              <p className="recipe-author-FEED">
                <Link style={{textDecoration: 'underline', color: 'rgb(230, 220, 200)'}} to={`/profile/${recipe.author}`}>
                  {recipe.username}
                </Link>
              </p>
            </Link>

            <Link to={{pathname: `/recipe/${recipe.id}`, component: 'Feed'}}>
              <h2 className="recipe-cooktime-FEED">{recipe.cooktime}</h2>
            </Link>
       </div>
```